# Why I'm getting wrong values when using ST_Area

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I Have created a table with the following commands:

```
  CREATE TABLE example (
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME CHAR(20),
    AGE INT,
    SEX CHAR(6),
    INCOME FLOAT,
    LOCATION geometry)
```

And inserted values with the following command:

```
INSERT INTO example (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, AGE,SEX,INCOME,LOCATION)
            VALUES ("b", "b", 30, "M", 500,  POLYGON((10 10, 10 20, 30 20, 30 30, 10 10)))
```

When I try to display the content with the area of the polygon, I'm getting wrong size:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, ST_Area(LOCATION) AS Area FROM example
```

I'm getting 0 (and I expect to get 200 (10*20))

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your polygon is not valid? It is crossing itself:

`POLYGON((10 10, 10 20, 30 20, 30 30, 10 10))`

[image]

The [`ST_Area`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) of such polygon will inevitably return zero:

```
SELECT 
 ST_Area('POLYGON((10 10, 20 10,20 30,30 30, 10 10))')

 st_area 
---------
       0
(1 Zeile)
```

On a first glance it seems you set the latitude value of the fourth coordinate pair wrong. It should be `30 10`, not `30 30`. Doing so you will get the `200` output you wished:

`POLYGON((10 10, 10 20, 30 20, 30 10, 10 10))`

[image]

```
SELECT 
 ST_Area('POLYGON((10 10, 10 20, 30 20, 30 10, 10 10))')

 st_area 
---------
     200
(1 Zeile)
```